# How to reverse an specific encryption

Tags: android, encryption

I have two code pieces. One to encrypt and another to decrypt. But the decryption code doesnt seem to work like i want it too :/

Encryption: `letter = ((letterInt + 1) * constant) modulus 29`

Encryption code line:

```
bogstaver[i-1] = alfabet.get(((alfabet.indexOf(bogstaver[i - 1]) + 1) * C) % 29);
```

Decryption: `letter = Int / constant, while (int / constant) modulus 1 = 0`

Decryption code:

```
D = alfabet.indexOf(bogstaver[i - 1]);

while ((D / C) % 1 != 0){
    D = D + 29;
}           
bogstaver[i - 1] = alfabet.get((D / C) - 1);
```

The letter I use in the encryption (`letterInt`) isn't the same as the letter I end up with after decryption (`letter`)

BTW, `alfabet` is a `List` with 29 characters

Comment: Remember that decryption has to have the opposite of all of encryption's operators, in OPPOSITE order, and if even a single operator is not negated correctly or is it out of order it will not work at all. I suggest using a debugger and testing every single one character string, stepping through the code for one that fails, to see which part of the process is not reversed correctly.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming so i dont really know how to debug :P could you explain that?

Comment: Do you use Netbeans or Eclipse? Either way, google for 'netbeans debugger' or 'eclipse debugger' and look for a guide. Debuggers are really awesome, they let you look at all your variables and values and step line by line through code :)

Answer (score 1):

What is this code `(D / C)%1` supposed to do?
Are you sure that modulo operator does work with floating operands? I'm not an android developer, but make sure that the expression in brackets isn't casted to an integer before modulo is counted. 
If that's the case then while loop terminates after first evaluation of the condition.
You could rewrite the condition to something like that:

```
while(D % C != 0){
...
}
```

Comment: The code is supposed to check if D / C dosnt have a result with decimals :) and then add 29 and try over

Comment: This looks like the only problem in your logic.